# When I try to install libboost-all-dev using apt-get, I get the error "unable to locate package libboost-all-dev"

Tags: apt, 16.10, boost

My system is ubuntu 64 bit, 16.10.

I have tried to 'sudo add-apt-repository universe', but 'universe' is already included in my sources. Other than that, what can I do to install libboost-all-dev?

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` after adding `universe`?

Comment: @muru Since it said that universe was already in sources, I did not think it necessary to run update after that. However, if you think I should run update, I can do that and will report back after that.

Comment: please do, and post any errors you get